# Pointstick doesn't work when other keyboard key is pressed

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, touchpad, dell-latitude

I am using a Dell Latitude E6430 (Windows 10 32-bit). I have this problem since I have bought it. The issue is, when I press a key on the keyboard, I can't use my pointstick (neither touchpad). This is quite of a crucial issue for me as I have problems playing games.

Comment: Install latest Dell Touchpad Driver.

Look for TouchCheck or PalmCheck, this prevents accidental mouse moves while typing, and might be configured wrong.

Comment: @davidbaumann Thanks for your reply. But can you guide me on how can I reach those configurations?

Comment: As it's a Dell, you will get the information from Dell.

Comment: @davidbaumann I disable TouchGuard in Dell Touchpad setting but it doesn't affect pointstick.